# In ArangoDB, Could I disable the V8 engine if we don't use any JS procedures?

Tags: arangodb

Could I disable the V8 engine to release the V8's huge memory usage, if we don't use any JS procedures?

And what features of ArangoDB are internally implemented by JavaScript?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't deactivate V8 inside of ArangoDB. A lot of the API is powered by JavaScript as well as most of the graph functionality. If you would 'deactivate' V8, ArangoDB would not work anymore.

If it is possible for you to share information on how you use ArangoDB and what memory usage you are seeing, please share it on [ArangoDB's mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/arangodb) or the [bugtracker](https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues). People there might be able to debug this behaviour or help you reduce your memory usage.

Comment: By the way, the number of v8 instances in ArangoDB can be configured using `--server.threads` (in 2.2) or `--javascript.v8-contexts` (2.3, preferred option).

Comment: I just read the offical FAQ at: 'https://www.arangodb.com/faq'. And it says: "In an empty ArangoDB, V8 actually accounts for most of the virtual memory usage. For example, on some 64 bit computer, the V8 threads in total consumed about 4 GB of virtual memory.".

Could I disable it If I totally don't need the graph model (we'll only use it as a document db with transaction support)?

Comment: No, that's not possible. The graph part is not the only part written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As of ArangoDB version 3.4 you can turn off V8 with:

```
--javascript.enabled false
--foxx.queues false
```

however, the following features will be unavailable:

- Backend parts of the web interface
- Foxx Apps
- Foxx Queues
- GraphQL
- JavaScript-based transactions
- User-defined AQL functions

Also, a note for clustered ArangoDB:

> Note that JavaScript / V8 can be disabled for DB-Server and Agency nodes in a cluster without these limitations. They apply to single server instances. They also apply to Coordinator nodes, but you should not disable V8 on Coordinators because certain cluster operations depend on it.

https://www.arangodb.com/2019/03/small-steps-reduce-arangodb-resource-footprint/